# SQL inner join match only once from both tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am struggling to figure out an efficient way to self inner join a table with 1m rows.

Table t with alias `t1` & `t2`:

```
Timestamp col1 col2
```

I want to do an inner join based on timestamp and col1 to match only once:

1. if there are many matches return the first one from the right table
2. AND the matched column is marked and cannot be used for next match

In pseudo code,

```
for v in t1.col1:
   if t1.timestamp - t2.timestamp < 5 mins AND t2.mark == False AND t1.col1 = t2.col1:
       t2.mark = true <- don't know how to do this in SQL
       return t1.timestamp, t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.timestamp, t2.col2
```

I have successfully achieved

1. if there are many matches return the first one from the right table

but not
2. AND the matched column is marked and cannot be used for next match

using `inner join` + `group by`.

In other words, there are t2 rows appearing multiple times in the result time (expect only one)

Sample input data:

```
Timestamp                    name price
2020-11-16 01:07:38.147501   A    1.0
2020-11-16 01:07:40.294957   A    1.2
```

Sample output data:

```
open_time                  close_time              name open_price close_price
2020-11-16 01:07:38.147501 2020-11-16 01:53:17.690113 A 1.0         1.5
```

1. In column open_time & close_time, they are unique in their column.
2. There are no overlap between any rows' open_time and close_time. In other words, for row 2's open_time, it must be later than row 1's close_time.

Probably this is related to cursor.

---

To simpify the question, consider I have the following records:

```
 open_time                  close_time              name open_price close_price
2020-11-16 01:07:38.147501,2020-11-16 01:53:17.690113, a, 1
2020-11-16 01:07:38.147501,2020-11-16 01:53:03.217847, a, 1.1
2020-11-16 01:07:40.294957,2020-11-16 01:53:17.690113, a, 1.2
2020-11-16 01:07:40.294957,2020-11-16 01:53:03.217847, a, 1.3
```

How do I make there are no overlap between open_time and close_time for all records?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks. Updated sample data. Does it make sense? @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question as saying that you have duplicates in the two tables and want to join them so only one duplicated row matches.

You can solve this by enumerating the rows in each table:

```
select . . .
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col, timestamp order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col, timestamp order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.col = t2.col and
        t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp and
        t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
```